# Using several timestamps in MYSQL \ Working with date zones

Tags: mysql, timezone, timestamp

I need to keep track of three dates in my table:

```
- created_at
- started_at
- finished_at
```

In the future I plan to make my scripts work with any time zone. As I know when I use timestamps they can be converted to any timezone, while datetime can't. But on the other hand it seems like not the best solution to have several timestamps in one table, and people usually use datetime for their tables.

So, if I want to work with timezones what should I use? Actually I even can't create a table with 3 timestamp columns (get some errors)

Update:

When I try to create a table with four timestamps I got a syntax error. Here is the code:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vs2`.`campaigns` (
  `starts_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,
  `ends_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
...
```

I removed unnecessary fields. I'm sure that the reason is that something's wrong with timestamps, because when I used datetime it worked nicely. I put default values because as I remember I had an issue that all timestamps were updated to the current date or something like that. When I remove default values for all timestamps except created_at I got:

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause
```

Comment: Do whatever suits you better, but certainly there should be ONE and only one timezone throughout your database. Otherwise it will be a hell of a job figuring out the time differences etc.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with keeping timestamps. They are useful because they are in UTC. That means you format the date according to the time zone at the point when you present (print, echo, whatever you prefer) the data to the user. As for datetime and why "people" use it - that doesn't mean you **have** to use datetime if a timestamp suits your needs better. If you want to work with timezones, you use timestamps because it's no trouble. If you use datetime, you have to ensure that all incoming dates are fixed to a certain time zone, otherwise you have incorrect data.

Comment: Well, as I think almost each web site should then use timestamps for such things as user registration etc, because If I live in another timezone I should get the right time? Anyway, I can't figure out why do I get an error when creating a table using timestamps (edited my post)